# Cleaning up the url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got this URL:

> http://domain.in/categories/chartered-accountants/

The **categories** part is the page name and **chartered-accountants** part is the parameter.

Using apache rewrite rules, I want to rewrite this URL to:

> http://domain.in/chartered-accountants/

My htaccess code is:

```
RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) categories.php?catName=$1
```

Comment: not clear what you mean, please provide more info

Comment: RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) categories.php?catName=$1

Comment: i have edited my question more breirfly . Now i hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

Even after your edit, it's still unclear what you're asking. You're saying that you want to rewrite this:

> http://domain.in/categories/chartered-accountants/

to this:

> http://domain.in/chartered-accountants/

Meaning that you want to drop the `categories` part. But your rewriterule is mentioning `categories.php?` which is completely unrelated to what you want. It's probably a copy/paste, right?

Anyway, in order to rewrite the first URL to the second one, you need something like this:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.in
RewriteRule ^categories/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,QSA]
```

It drops the `categories/` segment. You can [test it online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/):

[image: htaccess test]